# How can i get my Virtual Assistant to hear me?

Tags: python-3.x, speech-recognition, pyaudio

I am trying to build a virtual assistant for exercise, when i attempt to get audio using the microphone live 'Robin' (the V.A) will stay running.

I updated speechrecognitioin, pyaudio, and also reinstalled elasticsearch via homebrew after having to install java 1.8. I also tried adjusting the exception_on_overflow error after shutdown and set it '=False' (at this point i am much beyond my level of knowledge). On top of this to ensure the translation was working correctly i ran the -m speech recognition in terminal (OS: Mac) and it pretty accurately translated the speech. Im stumped.

```
# take command from microphone
def takeCommand():
    r = sr.Recognizer()
    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        print('Absorbing...')
        audio = r.listen(source)

    try:
        print('Recognizing...')
        query = r.recognize_google(audio, language='en-US')
        print(f'user said:{query}\n')

    except KeyboardInterrupt as e:
        print('Im sorry, I didnt get that.')


#Begin tasking:
speak('Initializing, Robin...')
wishMe()
takeCommand()
```

I am hoping for the console to return what i said into text, the goal would then to turn the text into an executable command. Hence the 'takeCommand' function. Yet if Robin cannot detect a sound she will give the output 'Im sorry,'. If theres anything else i can provide let me know. I really appreciate the feedback. Also Im new to stackoverfow I apologize if i didn't format this correctly.

Comment: Here is the error code after the force shutdown:

Comment: line 608, in read
    return pa.read_stream(self._stream, num_frames, exception_on_overflow)
KeyboardInterrupt

Process finished with exit code 1